# find the nearest postal codes based on one postal code in php

Tags: php

i have a database with postal codes of all state .i have config it in my data  base the fields are postcode,lat,log.
if i give one post code in my form and submit then i have to get the nearest postcode by specifing limited kilometers.
is there any php code to do this ?
please help me for this?

i have find some code to get distance

```
<?php
 function getDistance($latitude1, $longitude1, $latitude2, $longitude2) {  
    $earth_radius = 6371;  

    $dLat = deg2rad($latitude2 - $latitude1);  
    $dLon = deg2rad($longitude2 - $longitude1);  

    $a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) + cos(deg2rad($latitude1)) * cos(deg2rad($latitude2)) * sin($dLon/2) * sin($dLon/2);  
    $c = 2 * asin(sqrt($a));  
    $d = $earth_radius * $c;  

    return $d;  
}  

?>
```

like this how to find the nearest post code based on one post code.

Comment: Finding the nearest postcode is nothing I would do in php, but rather in the database itself. See for example this presentation on geo/spatial search with mysql: https://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

If it has to be done in php you are halfway there. You have a method that takes 2 pairs of lat,lon (which you have associated to each postcode) and returns the distance between them. So you can easily compare your postcode with all the others and then find the one with the smallest distance. If you encounter any problems, feel free to expand your question.

Comment: Totally agree with dbrumann, do the calculation in MySQL and only return the relevant results. Otherwise you would need to get _all_ postal codes from database first which is creating to much overhead. You can apply your PHP calculations to MySQL as well, it offers similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use sql query to select all postcode within the distance instead ##

```
    $distance=$_POST['specified_distance'];
        $search_postcode=$_POST['specified_postcode'];
        //use search postcode to get the row form database assume it to be searchrow
        $latitude=$searchrow['lat'];
        $longitude=$searchrow['long'];
        $sql = "SELECT *,(((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * sin((`lat`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) 
        * cos((`lat`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$longitude."- `long`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) 
        as distance
        FROM `MyTable`
        WHERE distance <= ".$distance;

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $postcode_rows=array();
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $postcode_rows[$row['distance']]=$row; //get each row to associative //array with distance as key
            }
 //do array krsort to get the least distance row;
        $sorted_postcodes_rows=krsort($postcodes);
        $selected_postcode_row=array_shift($sorted_postcodes); //get the nearest post //code
        echo =$nearest_postcode=$selected_postcode_row['postcode'];
        } else {
            echo "No nearest postalcode";
        }
```

Comment: Long live sql injection!